# C Polynomial Addition exercise

Tags: c, polynomials

I am currently working on an exercise for algorithm class. I was asked to write a C program which adds two polynomials entered by the user, which, I am able to do by asking the user the highest degrees of each polynomial and their coefficients.

The problem is that the input of the user must be something like for example `-5x4+2x2+6` (all coefficients and degrees can go from `0` to `9`).

I managed to convert this string to an array

```
void tableau(char *chaine) {
    int i = 0;
    while (1) {
        scanf("%c", &chaine[i]);
        if (chaine[i] == '\n') {
            break;
        } else {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

And I created a structure

```
struct polynome {
    int coeff;
    int degre;
};
```

I can't find a way to convert this array to a polynomial, here are all the functions I have written to make it work but I always get weird outputs:

```
int DEGREMAXTAB(char TAB[]) {
    int i = 0;
    int degre0 = 0;
    while (TAB[i] != '\0') {
        if (TAB[i] == 'x' && (int)(TAB[i+1]) > degre0)
            degre0 = (int)(TAB[i+1]);
        i++;
    }
    return degre0; // it returns the right highest degree + 48 for some reason, I don't know
}

void tabpoly(char chaine[], int degre0, struct polynome polynome[]) {
    int k = 1;
    int i = 0, a = 0, b = 0;
    
    while (chaine[i]) { // I am sorry, all of this is really messy, I just tried
        if (chaine[i] == '\0')
            break;
        
        if (chaine[i] == '-') {
            k = -1;
            i++;
        }
        if (chaine[i] == '+') {
            k = 1;
            i++;
        }
        if (chaine[i] != 'x') {
            a = k * ((int)(chaine[i]));
            i++;
        }
        i++;
        b = ((int)(chaine[i]));
        polynome[degre0].coeff = a;
        polynome[degre0].degre = b;
        degre0++;
        i++;
    }
}

void afficher(struct polynome poly[], int degre0) { /* maybe something is wrong here too I
really can't find the issue except by tweaking everything and causing other issues */
    int i = 0;
    char signe;
    for (i = degre0; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (poly[i].coeff < 0) {
            signe = '\0';
        } else {
            signe = '+';
        }
        printf("%c%dx%d", signe,poly[i].coeff, poly[i].degre);
    }
}
```

My main so far :

```
int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    struct polynome poly1[6]; // the maximum degree is 5
    int deg1 = 0, i = 0;
    char chainea[21];
    printf("Entrez votre premier polynôme\n");
    tableau(chainea);
    while (chainea[i] != '\0') {
        printf("%c",chainea[i]);
        i++;
    } // did this to check that there was no problem here
    
    deg1 = DEGREMAXTAB(chainea);
    printf("%d\n", deg1); // same, except that I must return deg1-48 and idk why
 
    tabpoly(chainea, deg1, poly1);
    afficher(poly1, deg1);   
}
```

I know my code might be really messy and I apologize for that, I would be glad if someone here could help me figure this out. Here is the output I have when typing the input from the example.

```
Entrez votre premier polynôme
-5x4+2x2+6
-5x4+2x2+6
4
-101x4+0x0+0x0+0x0+0x1Program ended with exit code: 0


Entrez votre premier polynôme
2x2
2x2
2
+2x2+0x0+0x1Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thank you really much, I tried to put as much information as I could. :)

Comment: `while(chainea[i] != '\0')` can fail as no `chainea[i]` was ever assigned a 0.  Maybe `if(chaine[i] == '\n') { chaine[i] = 0;  break; }`?

Comment: Also, 21 characters is not much and you will easily overflow it with even moderate polynomials. Your `tableau` is basically a re-implementation of the dreaded `gets` without null termination.

Comment: Inside DEGREMAXTAB...
if(TAB[i] == 'x' && (int)(TAB[i+1]) > degre0)
            degre0 = (int)(TAB[i+1]);
Unfortunately you cannot typecast a character to an integer.  You'll need to perform a more complex conversion. The numbers are stored as ASCII codes, so as long as you really only care about single digits, then simply substracting 48 will convert from ASCII to its integer value.

Comment: There are more places where you try to typecast a character that represents a digit to an integer value. In order to convert a single-digit number from a `char` to an `int` you have to subtract `'0'`. You forgot to initialize the structure array. In `tabpoly` you assign all values to `polynome[degre0]` strting from the maximum. Depending on how you implement the addition of the polynomials, you should either start from 0 or decrement the array index when adding the next term or use the current degree `b` as the array index and omit the `degree` field from the structure.

Comment: There seem to be more problems in the conversion from the string to the sructure array.

Comment: ...(continued)... Check the calculation of the degree for input with something like `...+2x+...` or `...+2x` or `...+2` at the end. In general it is a good idea to write down the expected behavior/input/output of individual functions and write test program that test a single function, e.g. feed different input strings into `tabpoly` and check the result. Run the program step-by-step in a debugger.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, it helped me a lot. However I still have a few problems, like for example when the user does not write a coefficient for every degree that is inferior to the highest one, I get something weird, do you know how I could improve this ? https://pastebin.com/aWc7eWpV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you should read the polynomial with a simple `fgets()` instead of reading one character at a time with `scanf()`. `scanf()` is not the best tool for that.
- the reason you get an offset of `48` is digits are ASCII characters, not integer values. You must subtract the value of `'0'` (which as the value `48` in ASCII) to get the corresponding number.
- you experience undefined behavior as you access elements in the `poly` array beyond the maximum index value because of the 48 offset. You should check that the exponent is within the proper range.
- you get random values because the `poly` array is uninitialized.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct polynome {
    int coeff;
    int degre;
};

int degremaxtab(const char tab[]) {
    int i, exp, max_exp = 0;
    for (i = 0; tab[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (tab[i] == 'x') {
            i++;
            if (tab[i] >= '0' && tab[i] <= '9') {
                exp = tab[i] - '0';
            } else {
                exp = 1;
            }
            if (max_exp < exp) {
                max_exp = exp;
            }
        }
    }
    return max_exp;
}

int skip_spaces(const char chaine[], int i) {
    while (chaine[i] == ' ' || chaine[i] == '\t' || chaine[i] == '\n') {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

/* return the maximum exponent in the polynomial */
int tabpoly(const char chaine[], struct polynome polynome[], int max_degree) {
    int i, max_exp, sign, coeff, exp;

    for (i = 0; i <= max_degree; i++) {
        polynome[i].coeff = 0;
        polynome[i].degre = i;
    }

    i = 0;
    max_exp = 0;
    while (chaine[i] != '\0') {
        i = skip_spaces(chaine, i);
        // get sign (allow +-)
        sign = 1;
        if (chaine[i] == '+') {
            i++;
        }
        i = skip_spaces(chaine, i);
        if (chaine[i] == '-') {
            sign = -1;
            i++;
        }
        i = skip_spaces(chaine, i);
        if (chaine[i] >= '0' && chaine[i] <= '9') {
            coeff = chaine[i] - '0';
            i++;
        } else {
            coeff = 1;
        }
        if (chaine[i] == 'x') {
            i++;
            if (chaine[i] >= '0' && chaine[i] <= '9') {
                exp = chaine[i] - '0';
                i++;
            } else {
                exp = 1;
            }
        } else {
            exp = 0;
        }
        i = skip_spaces(chaine, i);

        // check for a complete term
        if (chaine[i] != '\0' && chaine[i] != '+' && chaine[i] != '-')
            return -2;  // syntax error
        if (exp > max_degree)
            return -1;  // exponent too large
        if (max_exp < exp)
            max_exp = exp;
        polynome[exp].coeff += sign * coeff;
    }
    return max_exp;
}

void afficher(struct polynome poly[], int degre0) {
    int i, pos;
    /* simple output */
    for (i = degre0; i >= 0; i--) {
        printf("%+dx%d", poly[i].coeff, poly[i].degre);
    }
    printf("\n");
    /* clean output */
    pos = 0;
    for (i = degre0; i >= 0; i--) {
        int coeff = poly[i].coeff;
        int degre = poly[i].degre;
        if (coeff != 0) {
            if (coeff > 0) {
                if (pos > 0)
                    pos += printf("+");
                if (coeff != 1 || degre == 0)
                    pos += printf("%d", coeff);
            } else {
                if (coeff != -1 || degre == 0)
                    pos += printf("%d", coeff);
                else
                    pos += printf("-");
            }
            if (degre > 0) {
                printf("x");
                if (degre > 1)
                    pos += printf("%d", degre);
            }
        }
    }
    if (pos == 0) {
        printf("0");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    struct polynome poly1[6]; // the maximum degree is 5
    char chainea[100];
    int deg1;

    printf("Entrez votre premier polynôme\n");
    // read a full line from stdin
    if (!fgets(chainea, sizeof(chainea), stdin))
        return 1;

    deg1 = degremaxtab(chainea);
    printf("exposant maximum: %d\n", deg1);

    deg1 = tabpoly(chainea, poly1, 5);
    if (deg1 < 0) {
        if (deg1 == -1)
            printf("exposant trop grand\n");
        else
        if (deg1 == -2)
            printf("erreur de syntaxe\n");
        else
            printf("erreur\n");
    } else {
        afficher(poly1, deg1);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I added my addition/substraction algorithm to it and it all works ! As my account is brand new I cannot upvote your answer but it is exactly the solution to my problem. 

Comment: @aaa: you can accept the answer by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score, which should give you enough reputation to vote :) *Bonne Année !*

Comment: Alright thank you, _Merci, et bonne année à toi aussi !_

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution but the degrees are displayed in inverse; the constant is the first term. The indices are used as the degree of polynomial.
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct poly {
    int coef[9];
};

struct poly add(struct poly P1, struct poly P2) {
    struct poly result;
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        result.coef[i] = P1.coef[i] + P2.coef[i];
    }
    return result;
}
   
void display(struct poly P) {
    printf("%d + %dx", P.coef[0], P.coef[1]);
    for (int i = 2; i < 9; i++) {
        printf(" + %dx%d", P.coef[i], i);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
  
int main() {
    struct poly p1, p2, result;
    printf("Enter coefficients in order[Po 1]: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &p1.coef[i]);
    }
    printf("Enter coefficients in order[Po 2]: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        scanf("%d", &p2.coef[i]);
    }
    result = add(p1, p2);
    printf("\nThe Result is ");
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        printf("%d ", result.coef[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    display(result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If exponents can go up to `9`, the array `coef` should have a length of `10` to handle `0` to `9` inclusively.

Answer (score 0):

@sadbro: your answer has some problems:

- the array of coefficients should have a length of 10, and the loops should run to `i <= 9` or `i < 10`. Better even: define `MAX_POWER` to `9` and use it in the array size an `for` loops.
- if the coefficients are entered in increasing order, the output loop should iterate from the highest exponent down to `0`.
- you should not print the monomials with a `0` coefficient.
- you should not print the coefficients equal to `1` or `-1`.
- you should print negative coefficients without a leading `+`.
- it is more general to not print the trailing newline in `display()`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_POWER  9

struct poly {
    int coef[MAX_POWER + 1];
};

struct poly add(struct poly P1, struct poly P2) {
    struct poly result;
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_POWER; i++) {
        result.coef[i] = P1.coef[i] + P2.coef[i];
    }
    return result;
}

// return the number of bytes printed
int display(struct poly P) {
    int pos = 0;
    for (int i = MAX_POWER; i >= 0; i--) {
        int coefficient = P.coef[i];
        const char *prefix = "";
        if (coefficient != 0) {
            if (pos) {
                if (coefficient > 0) {
                    prefix = " + ";
                } else {
                    prefix = " - ";
                    coefficient = -coefficient;
                }
            } else {
                if (coefficient < 0) {
                    prefix = "-";
                    coefficient = -coefficient;
                }
            }
            pos += printf("%s", prefix);
            if (coefficient != 1) {
                pos += printf("%d", coefficient);
            }
            if (i > 1) {
                pos += printf("x%d", i);
            } else
            if (i == 1) {
                pos += printf("x");
            }
        }
    }
    if (pos == 0) {
        pos += printf("0");
    }
    return pos;
}
  
int main() {
    struct poly p1, p2, result;
    printf("Enter coefficients in order[Po 1]: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_POWER; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &p1.coef[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    printf("Enter coefficients in order[Po 2]: ");
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_POWER; i++) {
        if (scanf("%d", &p2.coef[i]) != 1)
            return 1;
    }
    result = add(p1, p2);
    printf("\nThe Result is");
    for (int i = 0; i <= MAX_POWER; i++) {
        printf(" %d", result.coef[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    display(result);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: well we can use a function to replace all zeroes to "". it will be more effective. C is too primitive, C++ would have done a better job.

Comment: and the newline that I entered was an intentional entree for aesthetic purposes.

Comment: @sadbro: I kept the newline, but moved it out of the `display()` function to the `main()` function so `display()` can be used to output a polynomial in the middle of a line.

Comment: @sadbro: what do you mean by *we can use a function to replace all zeroes to ""*? just replacing `"0"` with `""` only works if the coefficients are all single digits, but adding 2 such polynomials may break this assumption. C is too primitive, and C++ is very intricate... the choice is yours :)

Comment: @chqrlie thank you for your answers these are great but I think this is quite far from what I am coding isn't it?

Comment: @aaa: en effet, I posted a separate answer with more pertinent remarks and a modified version.

Comment: @chqrlie What I intended to say was that all the coefficents that are 0 and have + on left side should be replaced with "+ " ;;

Comment: @sadbro: such replacement would turn `0` coefficients into implied `1` coefficients. Your remark applies to `1` coefficients preceded by a `+` or `-` sign, not to `0` coefficients.

Comment: i meant for 1 and -1. what I meant for zero coefficients was that the x term should also disappear since there is no meaning in + 0x4 or something like that.

Comment: @sadbro: OK, we are in agreement. Instead of tricky post-processing, the above code handles these cases while generating the terms of the polynomial.